# Getting MIDI SoundNote Pitches as Numeric Values

Tags: sound

I'm trying to do some evaluation on notes (specifically the pitches) imported from a MIDI file. I've imported a list containing tracks of sound notes with `Import["path/to/midi.mid", "SoundNotes"]` and a track's sound notes look like the following:

```
{ SoundNote["G4", {0., 0.5}, "Piano", SoundVolume -> 0.501961], 
  SoundNote["C5", {0.5, 1.}, "Piano", SoundVolume -> 0.501961], 
  SoundNote["D5", {1., 1.5}, "Piano", SoundVolume -> 0.501961],
  ...
}
```

I'm attempting to get the pitch out of each SoundNote, treating each SoundNote as a list and grabbing the first value with `aNote[[1]]`. However, this returns a note string such as "C5". Is there a way to get a numeric representation of the pitch, in either MIDI scale (Middle C = 60) or Mathematica's scale (Middle C = 0)? I haven't seen any way to pull information from a SoundNote [in the docs](https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SoundNote.html), unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Good question.  If my memory serves me right, last time I did this I just created a replacement table `"C4" -> 0`, etc. and used that.  There might be something better though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If someone has a native solution I'll mark it as the correct answer, but I ended up making a quick function to convert the string into a numeric pitch. I go off the assumption that the MIDI import only uses sharps and no flats as representation for SoundNote pitch.

```
(* Converts note string into pitch relative to middle C = 0 *)
stringToPitch[string_String] := 
 Module[{noteValues, noteList, pitch},
   noteValues = {"C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B"};
   noteList = StringCases[string, {RegularExpression["[A-G]#?"], RegularExpression["\\d+"]}];
   pitch = Position[noteValues, First[noteList]][[1, 1]] - 1;
   ((ToExpression[noteList[[2]]] - 4)*12) + pitch
 ]
```

Note that this is relative to middle C like Mathematica tones (where C4 = MiddleC = 0). The function can be called as

```
stringToPitch["C#4"]

(* ==> 1 *)
```

Comment: +1 for providing a ready to use function.  I cleaned it up a bit, I hope you don't mind.  It is recommended not to use `Return` when it's not actually necessary and `pitch` was not localized.

Comment: Still getting used to the language, thanks for cleaning it up!

Comment: Noticed the `+ pitch` was accidentally removed, added it back to make sure the function is still correct. Feel free to further edit if necessary.